# Error 1 extracting ZIP file into temporary folder

Tags: r, zip, warnings, temp

The code was developed by eBird and can be found [here](https://cornelllabofornithology.github.io/ebird-best-practices/intro.html).

When I run the second set of code, this warning is produced and one cannot continue:

```
Warning message:
In unzip(tmp_bcr, exdir = tmp_dir) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

Here is the code that produces the error:

```
# download bcrs
tmp_dir <- normalizePath(tempdir())
tmp_bcr <- file.path(tmp_dir, "bcr.zip")
paste0("https://www.birdscanada.org/research/gislab/download/", 
       "bcr_terrestrial_shape.zip") %>% 
  download.file(destfile = tmp_bcr)
unzip(tmp_bcr, exdir = tmp_dir)
```

Could the slashes below be the issue when we look at the defined path on my PC?

```
> tmp_bcr
[1] "C:...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmpm8LNRB/bcr.zip"
```

Comment: What is your version of R? In the new R4.2.2 there was a bug fix regarding large zip files, see the [NEWS file](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.pdf), 3rd from last in section BUG FIXES.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the URL, it must have been changed and `download.file()` ends up fetching the content of `https://www.birdscanada.org/bird-science/national-geographic-information-systems-laboratory` . You can try to open/extract the resulting `bzr.zip` manually. And then open it with your preferred text editor. The correct URL seems to be `https://birdscanada.org/download/gislab/bcr_terrestrial_shape.zip`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Manual unzipping does not resolve the problem.

I am trying to recover RStudio GUI as the new R version as per @RuiBarradas caused issues but it's due to me changing default install paths. Any advice on this will also be appreciated.

Comment: @RuiBarradas the issue persists after upgrading to R 4.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `list = TRUE` I am getting a data.frame with the file names, their length and creation date.
And no errors extracting the files.

```r
tmp_dir <- normalizePath(tempdir())
tmp_bcr <- "~/Temp/bcr_terrestrial_shape.zip"
unzip(tmp_bcr, list = TRUE)
#>                                                            Name   Length                Date
#> 1                  BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_dissolve.CPG        5 2020-01-17 13:21:00
#> 2                  BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_dissolve.dbf     3662 2020-01-17 13:21:00
#> 3                  BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_dissolve.prj      167 2020-01-17 13:17:00
#> 4                  BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_dissolve.sbn     1068 2020-01-17 13:17:00
#> 5                  BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_dissolve.sbx      156 2020-01-17 13:17:00
#> 6                  BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_dissolve.shp  7091068 2020-01-17 13:21:00
#> 7              BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_dissolve.shp.xml    13760 2020-01-20 15:29:00
#> 8                  BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_dissolve.shx      892 2020-01-17 13:21:00
#> 9                    BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master.CPG        5 2020-01-17 13:11:00
#> 10                   BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master.dbf    83192 2020-01-17 13:11:00
#> 11                   BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master.prj      167 2020-01-17 13:11:00
#> 12                   BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master.sbn     3740 2020-01-17 13:11:00
#> 13                   BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master.sbx      252 2020-01-17 13:11:00
#> 14                   BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master.shp 13264916 2020-01-17 13:11:00
#> 15               BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master.shp.xml    15677 2020-01-20 15:29:00
#> 16                   BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master.shx     3084 2020-01-17 13:11:00
#> 17     BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master_International.CPG        5 2020-01-17 13:38:00
#> 18     BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master_International.dbf    11758 2020-01-17 13:38:00
#> 19     BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master_International.prj      167 2020-01-17 13:30:00
#> 20     BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master_International.sbn      820 2020-01-17 13:30:00
#> 21     BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master_International.sbx      156 2020-01-17 13:30:00
#> 22     BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master_International.shp 10235308 2020-01-17 13:30:00
#> 23 BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master_International.shp.xml    13795 2020-01-20 15:29:00
#> 24     BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master_International.shx      644 2020-01-17 13:30:00
#unzip(tmp_bcr, exdir = tmp_dir)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>